# Power App authentication with Azure ADB2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have an app that was developed using Angular 9 and we are using the login with  Azure AD B2C.
The users that we have in the  Azure AD B2C are Member(type).

We have a new requirement where we have to embed power apps in the web app (iframe tag - Canvas App), but we saw that always ask for sign in, but we want to re-use the token generated with the login to see the power app.

We created the power apps in the same directory as the Azure AD B2C and we shared it to everyone.
I tested the @microsoft/powerappsplayersdk sdk for angular but it's still not working, exists a getAccessToken function but neither works

Any ideas about what is missing? or what I have to do to avoid login again when I try to see a power app within my web application?

Answer (score 0):

What token issuer does power apps is expecting? Microsoft B2C token is issued by *.b2clogin.com endpoint and not by microsoftonline.com endpoint. This typically means that token issued by B2C cannot be used as-is by O365 and other services that don't accept B2C as a issuer.

Comment: So Is it not possible? =( The second authentication will be happening always?

Comment: As per Razi answer the second authentication needs to happen